# Difference of MONGODB C++ DRIVER mongocxx and legacy

Tags: c++, mongodb, driver, mongo-cxx-driver

On MongoDB's official [manual](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/), there are two drivers:
 mongocxx 3.0.x and legacy 1.1.x
I am puzzling which version to choose and what is their difference.

Thanks in advance for anyone could help me!

Comment: I believe I've answered your question, below. If you have any further questions, please follow up, but otherwise it is polite to 'accept' my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++11, you should absolutely use mongocxx. The legacy driver is just that, legacy. In fact, if you can't use C++11 for some reason, you might be better off just using the plain C driver. The legacy C++ driver does not implement the modern driver specifications, and is not receiving feature updates, only maintenance bugfixes.